# How do I reverse escape backslash encodings like "\ " and "\303\266" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I have a script that records files with UTF8 encoded names. However the script's encoding / environment wasn't set up right, and it just recoded the raw bytes. I now have lots of lines in the file like this:

```
.../My\ Folders/My\ r\303\266m/...
```

So there are spaces in the filenames with `\` and UTF8 encoded stuff like `\303\266` (which is `ö`). I want to reverse this encoding? Is there some easy set of bash command line commands I can chain together to remove them?

I could get millions of `sed` commands but that'd take ages to list all the non-ASCII characters we have. Or start parsing it in python. But I'm hoping there's some trick I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used something like this:

```
cat file | sed 's/%/%%/g' | while read -r line ; do printf "${line}\n" ; done | sed 's/\\ / /g'
```

Some of the files had `%` in them, which is a printf special character, so I had to 'double it up' so that it would be escaped and passed straight through. The `-r` in `read` stops read escaping the `\`'s however read doesn't turn `"\ "` into `" "`, so I needed the final `sed`.

Comment: If you use `printf "%b\n" $line` then it would not interpret `%` in $line.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a rough stab at the Unicode characters:

```
text="/My\ Folders/My\ r\303\266m/"
text="echo \$\'"$(echo "$text"|sed -e 's|\\|\\\\|g')"\'"
# the argument to the echo must not be quoted or escaped-quoted in the next step
text=$(eval "echo $(eval "$text")")
read text < <(echo "$text")
echo "$text"
```

This makes use of the `$'string'` quoting feature of Bash.

This outputs "/My Folders/My röm/".

As of Bash 4.4, it's as easy as:

```
text="/My Folders/My r\303\266m/"
echo "${text@E}"
```

This uses a new feature of Bash called [parameter transformation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). The `E` operator causes the parameter to be treated as if its contents were inside `$'string'` in which backslash escaped sequences, in this case octal values, are evaluated.

Comment: @Rory: Why do you think they call it "bash"?

Comment: Thank you. I have added additional quotes in the second line: `text="echo \$\'"$(echo \"$text\"|sed -e 's|\\|\\\\|g')"\'"` because of internal escaping issues with spaces (yes, not encoded ones).

Comment: @knalli: Those added quotes don't need to be escaped. But it works either way. I'm adding those plus some others to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear exactly what kind of escaping is being used.  The octal character codes are C, but C does not escape space.  The space escape is used in the shell, but it does not use octal character escapes.

Something close to C-style escaping can be undone using the command `printf %b $escaped`.  (The documentation says that octal escapes start with `\0`, but that does not seem to be required by GNU printf.)  Another answer mentions `read` for unescaping shell escapes, although if space is the only one that is not handled by `printf %b` then handling that case with `sed` would probably be better.

Comment: The 'encoding' is basically bash character escaping, (for the spaces), but where the encoding ENV isn't set up, so that it puts the raw octal numbers for the UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` to solve the issue with utf-8 text. Use `read` to take care of spaces `(\ )`.

Like this:

```
$ text='/My\ Folders/My\ r\303\266m/'
$ IFS='' read t < <(printf "$text")
$ echo "$t"
/My Folders/My röm/
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in 'read' function will handle part of the
problem:

```
$ echo "with\ spaces" | while read r; do echo $r; done
with spaces
```

Comment: that was my first attempt, and it does do the spaces, but it does not do the utf8 conversion. For example, $ echo "with\ spaces \303\266" | while read r ; do echo $r ; done
with spaces 303266

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file (line by line) to the following perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/per

sub encode {
    $String = $_[0];
    $_ = $String;
    while(/(\\[0-9]+|.)/g) {
        $Match = $1;

        if ($Match =~ /\\([0-9]+)/) {
            $Code = oct(0 + $1);
            $Char = ((($Code >= 32) && ($Code  160))
                ? chr($Code)
                : sprintf("\\x{%X}", $Code);
            printf("%s", $Char);
        } else {
            print "$Match";
        }
    }

    print "\n";
}

while ($#ARGV >= 0) {
    $File = shift();
    open(my $F, ") {
        $String =~ s/\\ / /g;
        &encode($Line);
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
$ ./PerlEncode.pl Test.txt
```

Where Test.txt contains:

```
/My\ Folders/My\ r\303\266m/
/My\ Folders/My\ r\303\266m/
/My\ Folders/My\ r\303\266m/
```

The line "$String =~ s/\ / /g;" replace "\ " with " " and sub encode parse those unicode char.

Hope this help